# Draw verticle Line with circle along side listview in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to achieve

this will be vertical line which will run along with the list view. There is a small circle which will be in middle of each cell in list view.

I tried

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
                        VStack {
                            Path { path in
                                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.height / 2, y: 3))
                                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.height / 2, y: geometry.size.width))
                            }
                            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle( lineWidth: 3))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
                        }
                    }
```

this creates a solid line vertically but not able to achieve desired result, also not able to figure out how to place circle in middle of each content.

**Update :**
I tried below code and it was close to my UX requirement

```
import SwiftUI

struct VerticleLineCircle: View {
let array: Array<Int> = Array(0...10)


public var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
    VStack {
        ForEach(0..<array.count) { index in
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                        VStack {
                            Path { path in
                                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.height / 2, y: -10))
                                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.height / 2, y: geometry.size.width))
                            }
                            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle( lineWidth: 2))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        }
                    }
                Text("Hello, here is some custom view!")
                HStack {
                        Circle().fill(Color.blue)
                            .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                            .position(x: 15, y: 0)
                        Line()
                            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0.5))
                            .frame(height: 1)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(80))
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
}

 struct Line: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: -150, y: -5))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0))
        return path
         }
  }


  struct SwiftUIView3_Previews: PreviewProvider {
       static var previews: some View {
            VerticleLineCircle()
       }
   }
```

**but still few things are missing
i.e at index 0 and last I want line to end in middle of view with circle**

[image]

Comment: I think it is just not possible with using List, maybe in a custom way.

Comment: You’ve changed the requirements and your code has a lot going on it would require a lot of refractoring. All your values are hard coded and likely yield inconsistent views depending on the device.

Comment: @loremipsum: I think you and me would be millionaires when we updated all our answers to changed questions. Such a nice payment! I cannot ignore it.

Comment: @swiftPunk The OP deleted the comment were they came around. It is the thrill of the puzzle for me. This was a simple one.

Comment: @loremipsum: Yeah he did the same to me as well, it happens time to time to me as well when I get such OP like this one that they bargaining for update and forgetting that we put our time for this! Idk! I just answered the issue as fun, if I cloud answer it without using path! otherwise I would delete my answer, maybe I keep it for others to see or use.

Answer (score 4):

Not with `List` because it has custom `padding` that would leave gaps but you can do it with a `VStack` inside a `ScrollView`

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomListView: View {
    ///How far from the left edge
    let start: CGFloat = 15
    ///Padding between margin and your row content
    let padding: CGFloat = 16
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack(spacing: 0){
                ForEach(0..<10){ n in
                    VStack{
                        //if the item is the first element
                        if n == 0{
                            CustomRowMarginView(start: start, rightPadding: padding, postion: .start){
                                Text("Your row Content goes here \(n)")
                            }
                        }
                        //if the item is the last element
                        else if n == 9{
                            CustomRowMarginView(start: start, rightPadding: padding, postion: .end){
                                Text("Your row Content goes here \(n)")
                            }
                        }
                        //if the item is the middle element
                        else{
                            CustomRowMarginView(start: start, rightPadding: padding, postion: .mid){
                                Text("Your row Content goes here \(n)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: CGFloat(Int.random(in: 20...100)))
                    Divider().padding(.leading, start + padding)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomRowMarginView<Content:View>: View {
    ///How far from the left edge
    let start: CGFloat
    ///Padding between margin and your row content
    let rightPadding: CGFloat
    let color: Color = Color(UIColor.systemBlue)
    let content: Content
    let postion: CustomLineShape.Position
    init(start: CGFloat, rightPadding: CGFloat, postion: CustomLineShape.Position = .mid, @ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content){
        self.start = start
        self.rightPadding = rightPadding
        self.postion = postion
        self.content = content()
    }
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            ZStack(alignment: .leading){
                CustomLineShape(start: start, postion: postion)
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle( lineWidth: 3))
                    .foregroundColor(color)
                CustomDotShape(start: start, postion: postion)
                    .fill(color)
            }
            .frame(width: start + rightPadding)
            content
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    
}
struct CustomLineShape: Shape {
    let start: CGFloat
    let postion: Position
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        if postion == .start || postion == .mid{
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: start, y: postion == .start ? rect.midY : rect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start, y: rect.maxY))
        }else{
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: start, y: rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start, y: rect.minY))
        }
        return path
    }
    enum Position{
        case start
        case end
        case mid
    }
}
struct CustomDotShape: Shape {
    let start: CGFloat
    let postion: CustomLineShape.Position
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        if postion == .start {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: start, y: rect.midY ))
        }else{
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: start, y: rect.minY))
        }
        
        path.addRelativeArc(center: CGPoint(x: start, y:  postion == .start || postion == .end ? rect.midY : rect.minY), radius: 5, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), delta: Angle(degrees: 360), transform: .identity)
        return path
    }
    
}
struct CustomListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomListView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for. It supports dynamic height for each row. Awesome! I was using a ZStack for line and HStack for bullet / row content. There was alot of unexpected behavior. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here another approach using a custom way I call it **VerticalLineInForEachView**, we cannot use List for this work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let array: Array<Int> = Array(0...10)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VerticalLineInForEachView(sizeOfCircle: 20.0, widthOfLine: 2.0, padding: 5.0, colorOfCircle: .black, colorOfLine: .red, showDivider: true, array: array) { index in
            
            HStack {
                
                CustomView(index: index)
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.yellow.opacity(0.2).cornerRadius(16))
            .padding(.vertical, 5.0)
            .padding(.trailing)
        }
        .padding(.leading, 5.0)
        
        
    }
    
}


struct VerticalLineInForEachView<Content: View, T>: View {
    
    let sizeOfCircle: CGFloat
    let widthOfLine: CGFloat
    let padding: CGFloat
    let colorOfCircle: Color
    let colorOfLine: Color
    let showDivider: Bool
    let array: Array<T>
    @ViewBuilder let content: (Int) -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0.0) {
                
                let upperBound: Int = array.count - 1
                
                ForEach(array.indices, id: \.self, content: { index in
                    
                    VStack { content(index) }
                        .padding(.leading, (sizeOfCircle/2.0 + padding))
                        .overlay(((index != upperBound) && (index != 0)) ? colorOfLine.frame(width: widthOfLine).offset(x: -widthOfLine/2.0) : nil , alignment: .leading)
                        .overlay(((index == upperBound) || (index == 0)) ?
                                    
                                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                                        
                                        colorOfLine
                                            .frame(width: widthOfLine, height: proxy.size.height/2.0)
                                            .offset(x: -widthOfLine/2.0, y: (index == 0) ? proxy.size.height/2.0 : 0.0)
                                        
                                    }
                                    
                                    : nil , alignment: .leading)
                        .overlay(Circle().fill(colorOfCircle).frame(width: sizeOfCircle, height: sizeOfCircle).offset(x: -sizeOfCircle/2.0) , alignment: .leading)
                        .overlay(((index != upperBound) && showDivider) ? Color.secondary.opacity(0.2).frame(height: 2).offset(y: 1).padding(.horizontal).padding(.leading, sizeOfCircle) : nil, alignment: .bottom)
                    
                } )
                
            }
            .padding(.leading, sizeOfCircle/2.0)
            
        }
        
    }
    
}


struct CustomView: View {
    
    let index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let randomSize: CGFloat = CGFloat.random(in: 50.0...250.0)
        
        if index.isMultiple(of: 2) {
            
            if Bool.random() {
                
                Circle().fill(Color.blue).frame(width: randomSize, height: randomSize, alignment: .center)
            }
            else {
                Image(systemName: "books.vertical").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: randomSize, height: randomSize, alignment: .center)
            }
            
        }
        else {
            
            if Bool.random() {
                
                Text(" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
                
            }
            else {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @AT9: My answer is good and no need for update, you cannot update your question time to time for other issue, or salving small issues! and thanks means up vote or accepting it as answer here.